# Binding not updating when component property changed in callback

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, rxjs

I'm creating a Chrome extension with Angular to render a pop-up window.  The view binding is not updating when a callback comes from the Chrome API and a property used in the view binding is altered as of a result of that callback.  Adding additional complication, the callback isn't called directly but wrapped in an Observable.

If I call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` then the view is updating appropriately.  I tried using NgZone but I may be using it wrong - it has no effect if I include it or exclude it from the method that creates my observable.

#### Relevant Component Code

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.port = chrome.runtime.connect({ name: 'PopupToBackground' });
  // ChromeUtil is an injected service wrapping chrome API calls.
  this.chromeUtil.portOnMessage$(this.port).pipe(
    tap((x: string) => {
      // text is the bound property
      this.text = x || 'no data';
      // Uncomment line below and everything works.
      //this.cd.detectChanges();
    })
  ).subscribe();
}
```

#### Relevant ChromeUtil Code

```ts
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ChromeUtil {
  constructor(private zone: NgZone) { }

  portOnMessage$(port: chrome.runtime.Port) {
    return new Observable<any>(subscriber => {
      return this.zone.run(() => {
        const listener = (msg: any) => subscriber.next(msg);
        port.onMessage.addListener(listener);
        return { 
          unsubscribe() { 
            port.onMessage.removeListener(listener); 
          } 
        };
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: So is there a question actually? ;) if it works with triggering change detection manually, is there an issue?

Comment: @AJT_82 calling `detectChanges()` manually is not an ideal solution. The question is what's wrong with his zones.

Comment: @cgTag Sure, I just don't see a question anywhere, so that was rather my point. If there is an issue with triggering change detection (apparently not), but then... what is the question.

Comment: I see what the problem is. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onMessage` events are executing outside of Angular, and you need to call `zone.run()` to trigger change detection. You almost have it, but are calling `run()` at the wrong point.

```
portOnMessage$(port: chrome.runtime.Port) {
    return new Observable<any>(subscriber => {
        const listener = (msg: any) => this.zone.run(() => subscriber.next(msg));
        port.onMessage.addListener(listener);
        return {
            unsubscribe() {
                port.onMessage.removeListener(listener);
            }
        };
    });
}
```

The callback passed to `port.onMessage.addListener()` is executed outside of Angular. It's this callback that must be run inside the zone.

```
  // Uncomment line below and everything works.
  //this.cd.detectChanges();
```

If your component is using `OnPush` change detection, then you'll have to call `this.cd.markForCheck()` as you would with any external observable for a component. The alternative is to use the `async` pipe in the template.